# The right way capturing prvalue in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11

What is the correct practice capturing return value of `boost::make_iterator_range` in following scenarios:

1. When used in range based for loop:

   ```
   for (auto&& val : boost::make_iterator_range(...))//  <-- is `auto&&` the right way?
   ```
2. When used as formal parameter:

   ```
   DoStuff(boost::make_iterator_range(...));

   template<class Iterator>
   void DoStuff(Iterator&& it){}//  <-- is Iterator&& the right way?
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (auto&& val : boost::make_iterator_range(...))//  <-- is `auto&&` the right way?
```

The return value of `make_iterator_range` is not stored in `val`.  `val` simply stores the return value of the dereferencing of the iterators: the element, not the entire range.

`auto&&` creates a forwarding reference to the element.

```
DoStuff(boost::make_iterator_range(...));

template<class Iterator>
void DoStuff(Iterator&& it){}//  <-- is Iterator&& the right way?
```

Using the name `Iterator` belies a misunderstanding: `make_itetator_range` is not an iterator, it is a range defined by iterators.

```
template<class Range>
void DoStuff(Range&& r){}
```

This does not change the behaviour of the code, but it was like having a variable of type `int` named `Double`: pointlessly or aggressively confusing.

In any case, `Range&& r` in this context is also a forwarding reference.

A forwarding reference in a type deduction context can bind to either an lvalue or rvalue.  It can cause reference lifetime extension as well.

---

In both of these situations, `auto&&` and `Range&&` are reasonable approaches, but so would `auto const&`, `auto&` or `auto` in the first case, and in the second `Range const&` or `Range` have their advantages.  They just mean different things.

So your solutions are one way that can be right, but there is no "one right way" for what to put there.  I use forwarding references by default, but that is a matter of taste: others might choose to default to `const&` or values.  And in some contexts, `auto&` would be proper (where your loop modifies the value and intends that modification to persist).

Comment: 1) `auto` and `Range` approach can cause an unnecessary copying 2) `Range const&` will make in unmutable

Comment: Regarding the `for` loop, `auto` would work in all cases but it implies a copy of the object (which may not be wanted) and `auto&` might not work in some cases (when the iterator does not return a reference, typically `std::vector<bool>`).

Comment: @alej if in your use case the copy is not necessary or desired, then yes it will.  And mutating data that is about to be discarded, or that you do not intend to mutate, is usually bad.  Again *it depends* on what use you have for the referred to data.  Defaulting to `const` means defaulting to non-mutating code, the  making it mutate (away from `const&`) only when you actually need it.  They *do different things*, if your code wants different things, use a different one.

Comment: @AlejandroFreeman True, but maybe you want a copy ;) You cannot say *"I'm gonna use `auto&&` everywhere because it will "work" everywhere."*, you should know the difference between the 4 versions and use the correct one depending on what you really want.

Comment: If in my first case I want to mutate the data `auto&` should also work right ?

Comment: @alej are the iterators returning proxy pseudo-reference objects (ie, are not "real iterators" on a real conttainer) or real references?  If real references, yes.

Comment: I'm using `boost::make_iterator_range` with `boost::zip_iterator`, so dereferencing it returns proxy object (I think it's boost::tuple).